# S#arp Architecture 1.9 + Multi Tenant Custom View Engine

Tags: s#arp-architecture, multi-tenant, viewengine

What is the easiest way to create a Custom AreaViewEngine that S#arp uses?

I want to add another directory to search for view for the current tenant, the tenant directory would be part of the domain name (e.g. hm.com), so i would like my view engine to check:

/Tenants/hm.com/Views/Home/Index.aspx

I tried to create a new TenantViewEngine.cs inherited from the AreaViewEngine to add my new paths but I can't get access to the HttpContext to get the host name.

Any ideas?

Thanks.
Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HttpContext.Current should be available. Also, ControllerContext passed as a parameter to Find* and Create* methods has a HttpContext property.

You might also want to look at the [VirtualPathProviderViewEngine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.virtualpathproviderviewengine.aspx) class.

Comment: thank you, i was trying to do it the simple way by just overriding the constructor. But in the end I had to implement many methods such as FindView, FindPartielView, GetPath, GetSpecificPathName etc. All working perfectly now thank you.